# Joining SAS data to a Teradata table

Tags: sql, sas, database-connection, teradata

Using:  SAS Enterprise Guide 7.13

OBJECTIVE: I'm trying to Inner Join a SAS table to a table in Teradata using SAS EG without using a sub-query.

Note: I do not have write privileges other than volatile tables in Teradata.

My current approach below is yielding the following error.
ERROR: Teradata prepare: Database '&USDomID.E' does not exist.
The error is taking place when creating the XREF_CAK table using the connection to Teradata.

```
PROC SQL;
            CONNECT TO TERADATA (USER=&tuserid. PASSWORD=&tpswd. TDPID=DWPROD2 CONNECTION=GLOBAL MODE=TERADATA SCHEMA=EDW_ALLPHI);

            CREATE TABLE xin AS
            SELECT DISTINCT 
            &xref_cak. AS XREF_CAK,
            adjdctn_dt
            FROM
            &datain.;
            QUIT;

LIBNAME &USDomID.E TERADATA USER=&tuserid. PASSWORD=&tpswd. TDPID=xxxx CONNECTION=GLOBAL DBMSTEMP=YES TPT=NO MODE=TERADATA; 

        PROC SQL;
            CONNECT TO TERADATA (USER=&tuserid. PASSWORD=&tpswd. TDPID=xxxx CONNECTION=GLOBAL MODE=TERADATA SCHEMA=EDW_ALLPHI);
        %dropvts(myxref)
        QUIT;


        PROC SQL;
        PROC APPEND DATA=xin BASE=&USDomID.E.myxref (TPT=NO MULTISTMT=YES);
        RUN;

PROC SQL;
CONNECT TO TERADATA (USER=&tuserid. PASSWORD=&tpswd. TDPID=xxxx CONNECTION=GLOBAL MODE=TERADATA SCHEMA=EDW_ALLPHI);

CREATE TABLE XREF_CAK AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM CONNECTION TO TERADATA (
      SELECT
        CLM_SOR_CD,
        CLM_ADJSTMNT_KEY,
        SRC_SBSCRBR_ID,
        SRC_MBR_SQNC_NBR,
        CONCAT('SCCF ',CLM_ITS_SCCF_NBR) AS CLM_ITS_SCCF_NBR_FORMATTED, CAST(CLM_ITS_SCCF_NBR_FORMATTED AS varchar(35)),
        CASE
            WHEN CLM_SOR_CD ='822' THEN 'AC'
            WHEN CLM_SOR_CD ='823' THEN 'CF'
            WHEN CLM_SOR_CD ='869' THEN 'CH'
            WHEN CLM_SOR_CD ='809' THEN 'CS'
            WHEN CLM_SOR_CD ='824' THEN 'NA'
            WHEN CLM_SOR_CD ='808' THEN 'WG'
            WHEN CLM_SOR_CD ='889' THEN 'VAITS'
        ELSE CLM_SOR_CD
        END AS SOR_CD_TXT,CAST(SOR_CD_TXT AS varchar(5)),
        CONCAT(SOR_CD_TXT,',',SRC_SBSCRBR_ID,',',SRC_MBR_SQNC_NBR,',',CLM_ITS_SCCF_NBR_FORMATTED) AS XREF_CAK_CONCAT, CAST(XREF_CAK_CONCAT AS varchar(100))
    FROM EDW_ALLPHI.CLM
INNER JOIN
    &USDomID.E.myxref x on
x.XREF_CAK = c.clm_adjstmnt_key and
x.adjdctn_dt = c.adjdctn_dt     
    );

DISCONNECT FROM TERADATA;
QUIT;
```

Comment: Anything via SQL Passthrough means that the server cannot see you SAS data set so it cannot work. You have to pull the information separately and join or use a macro variable to filter the list using a WHERE statement instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this to work. Code below for anyone that has this same issue. The key was getting the libname setup correctly with DBMSTEMP=YES TPT=No included

```
%let ID=%scan(%qsysfunc(dequote(&tuserid)), 1, @);

/*set Teradata connection libref*/
libname &ID. teradata user="%qsysfunc(dequote(&tuserid))" password="%qsysfunc(dequote(&tpswd))"  TDPID=XXXX connection=global DBMSTEMP=YES TPT=No MODE=TERADATA SCHEMA=XXXX;

DATA MY_XREF_SAS;
SET  &datain.;
RUN;

/*loads unique XREF_CAKs set into Teradata*/
DATA &ID..MY_XREF (MULTISTMT=YES);
SET  &datain.;
RUN;

PROC SQL FEEDBACK;
    CONNECT TO TERADATA (USER=&tuserid. PASSWORD=&tpswd. TDPID=XXXXX CONNECTION=GLOBAL MODE=TERADATA SCHEMA=XXXXX);

Create Table XREF as SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO TERADATA(
      SELECT
        c.COL1,
        c.COL2,
        c.COL3,
        c.COL4,
        CONCAT('SCCF ',c.COL5) AS COL5_FORMATTED, CAST(COL5_FORMATTED AS varchar(35))
    FROM XXXXX.XXX c
INNER JOIN &ID..MY_XREF x on
x.XREF_CAK = c.clm_adjstmnt_key 
    );

drop table &ID..MY_XREF;

DISCONNECT FROM TERADATA;
QUIT;
```

Comment: When making two connections, LIBNAME and CONNECT,  be sure they have same settings or you will end up with two connections and the second one will not see the temporary tables made with the first one.  Did you try `CONNECT USING &ID.` syntax in your SQL block instead of spelling out your connection details?  Last time I used Teradata you could not use TPT with temporary tables.  If you could get admins to give you small personal or team database where you could create real tables you could use TPT to upload there.